# Java Array Output With Quotes

Tags: java, arrays, quotes

I am writing a code for a Playlist where the input string  contain name of videos God, Love, Success and Mind. With the code below I have been succesful  to attach the extention .mp4, i.e. the output of the code is:

```
God.mp4
Love.mp4
Success.mp4
Mind.mp4
```

But I need the output with quotes for every mp4 as

```
"God.mp4"
"Love.mp4"
"Success.mp4"
"Mind.mp4"
```

Help me to change the following code to get this required output.

```
   public static void   modifyArray( String array2[] )
   {


  for ( int video = 0; video < array2.length; video++ )
     array2[ video ] =  array2[ video ]+".mp4";


  for ( int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++ )
      System.out.println( array2[i]);

 }  


   public static void main( String[] args )
   {


   String umesh="God Love Success Mind";

    try {
    String[] umesh2 = umesh.split("\\s+");
    modifyArray( umesh2 ); // pass array reference

  } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
     // 
}
 }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the quotes to the output:

```
System.out.println("\"" + array2[i] + "\"");
```

The backslash is the escape character which allows you to use quotes inside strings.